# Is there any wargame-like for Substrate?

Tags: learning, security, tutorials

In my opinion, the best way to learn things is by practicing. The Substrate's tutorial (and docs) are already great on that matter.

But I have to say that I miss something around security there. I remember how I got excited when I first met the [overthewire's wargames](https://overthewire.org/wargames/) and later the [OpenZeppelin's Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/).

Those are exactly the way I like to learn new stuff, coding to solve challenges with a huge dose of gamification to keep me addicted! =)

So, is there anything like that already in production or even as a PoC?

Is so, I'd like to connect with the maintainers to help they on improvements.

And if there isn't, I already have an initial dev team to create a PoC and then try to fund the project by creating a Treasury's proposal.

Any idea or feedback is more than welcome, thanks!

PS: I'm aware of [pallet-chaos](https://github.com/paritytech/pallet-chaos) and it would be definitely used in the project.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any wargame like gamification in the spirit of OpenZeppinls Ethernauts and I agree that it might be an interesting and motivating learning experience around Substrate.

If you want to experience some gamification around Substrate, you might enjoy checking out [Open Emoji Battler](https://github.com/OpenEmojiBattler/open-emoji-battler). While it is not targeting security, it is at least a fully decentralised on-chain game which AFAIK was realised either as a standalone chain or as an ink! Smart Contract.